# Codeigniter/PHP delete row after period of time

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Is it possible to delete a SQL db row after a period of time?

ie.  I have a row that has an expiration date and it needs to be deleted on that day?

If I'm displaying info to a user, is it better practice to just hide "expired" entries and keep the data?

Comment: It's usually best to keep the data - you never know what you might need them for - auditing purposes, as evidence in case of trouble... Some data, of course, one is not allowed to keep under the many new (and good) privacy laws. It really depends on what kind of data you're talking about.

Comment: It's just a list of generated promotional codes...each of which has an expiration date...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either way this looks like a job for [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Just create a cron job that runs daily that either deletes or hides the rows that expire that day. I prefer to hide them for data retention purposes but deleting them might suit your application better. You'll know better then us.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can always call it like this:

[image]

Afterwards you go to your cpanel to set a time interval that executes a script periodically.